# How do I use get.snackbar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Whenever I try to call  get.snackbar, no snackbar is shown? According to the pub.dev page, I just need to use

```
Get.snackbar(
                  'User 123',
                  'Successfully created',
                );
```

But whenever I use that in my code, no snackbar is shown? Am I using it wrongly? thank you for your help!

Comment: final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));

// Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar.
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar); [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars) check it

Comment: Ok but what if I don't have context (which is why I wanna use Get)

Comment: @Emmanuel please check my answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(    // You need to change Material App to GetMaterialApp
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter - Snackbar USing Get'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.snackbar(
                      'User 123',
                      'Successfully created',
                      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM
                  );
                },
              ),

            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: but its a too bottom , how to add gap or just margin bottom 8 so its not toch soo bottom position .